# INDEX and MATCH in Excel providing results 1 row lower than desired

Tags: microsoft-excel

In using INDEX and MATCH to perform a multiple-condition VLOOKUP, I'm currently getting results for the desired column using the below formula, but the result is consistently 1 row lower than desired.

```
{=INDEX($A$2:$E$1200,MATCH(1,(A:A=A2)*(E:E="WS01"),0),3)}
```

In the attached image, we see Row 4's S/N returned for row 3's result in finding a "WS01" entry. If I replace the multiplier (*) in MATCH with an addition, I get the correct result for the first store (#2), but then for all following rows, the formula ends up providing row 4's S/N (REG01), so that doesn't seem to be the right path either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way those functions work is the following

Index takes an array (A2,A3,A4...) as well as a number

=Index(A2:A4,2) would return the value in A3 since it is the second cell in the array.

Match looks through an array and returns the number of the cell it would be found in (2nd cell, 4th cell, etc) it doesn't return the actual cell position.

So by not using matching arrays in the two functions

- Index uses C2:C1000
- Match uses A:A

You are causing your mismatch.  Match function finds that in the 3rd line (A3) everything matches so it returns a 3.

Index then takes (C2:C1000,3) and it returns the 3rd cell which happens to be C4 not C3.

Note for the array function you can just use C2:C1000, not A2:E1000 then you can omit the column part of the function.

Comment: I don't follow. My INDEX array is $A$2:$E$1200, not C2:C1000. Can you clarify, or provide an example?

Comment: @DavidMetcalfe your `INDEX()` array starts at row 2. Your `MATCH()` array starts at row 1. That is the problem. They both have to start at the same row.

Comment: @Kyle Ah, I see what you mean and what gtwebb was likely trying to point out now.

Comment: Yes indeed, my note at the end was that you don't need to say A2:E1200 if you are only returning values from column C.